# Connect to Sagemcom 3184 router with telnet or ssh

Tags: router, wireless-router, putty

I tried to connect to my router (Sagemcom f@st 3184) with Putty via SSH or Telnet, and I get the error "Connection refused". I tried to forward the port of SSH in the configuration of the router, but it didn't work.

What I need to do?

Comment: What you need to do in the first place - is provide more details about your set up

Comment: which information ?

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding would allow someone from the external internet to access the port of a computer inside the network.

So you are at a cafe for example, and you've port forwarded port 80 to a computer inside your home network.  Now when you connect to the router on port 80 it will forward the request to that computer and send the responses back to your laptop in the cafe